Open URL Only Works in Main Storyboard View Controller, Will Not Work in the Multiple Screen View Controllers
I have a single storyboard with 4 screens (segue to each ViewControllers).
An Open Url sequence WILL NOT WORK on any of the additional 3 screen ViewControllers.
It only works on the main View Controller or on a separate storyboard (manual segue).
The View Controllers were created using Cocoa Touch Class: UIViewController.
Throws this error:
Thread 1: "[<UIViewController 0x10b318630> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key WebButton."
I've wiped all possible stray connections.
This code works perfectly fine ONLY on the main and separate storyboards:
@IBAction func GoToWebsite(_ sender: UIButton)  {
        
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            
        }
    }

I am missing some bit of information...
Thank you.

I could not comment on your article in the PHP Collective.  Why not post your content in the normal Q&A?

SOLVED
I deleted the three ScreenControllers and started again.
This time, it worked.
 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯


Your problem is probably some mismatch in outlets or a Button missing. It's looking for "WebButton" which does not exist. Maybe the name is different? It's hard to say exactly whats wrong without seeing the setup.

However, it works without any problems when creating the same setup from scratch in the main ViewController or in the 2nd Storyboard.

As I said without more details it's difficult to help. There probably is something missing.
